# YouTube API PHP - Trouble retrieving full video description

Tags: php, google-api, youtube-api, google-api-php-client

I've been playing around with the [google/google-api-php-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client). I've noticed that it says "build-failing", but some parts are working as expected, so I've been pressing on with it.

So I have built a search field that queries the YouTube API for videos containing a search string and prints the results. You'll see that I've also hooked up the YouTube Player iFrame API to play the video if it is clicked.[image: YouTube API Search Results]

Now these results do contain snippet data (title, description, channelId, etc...), but the item description's are limited to 160 characters and appended with an ellipsis `…`.

[image: print of search/list response]

So now in an attempt to get a full description, I am sending another call to the YouTube API. I am calling `$youtube->videos->listVideos('snippet',array('id' => '7dR02ebri9c'))`. The call is successful, but does not contain any snippet data.

I've logged the response to the console so you can see it here:
[image: console log of videos/listVideos response]

And printed it here incase the above image does not show.
`{"etag":"\"43qFkeEQBKio26KDSq1ZQMzjhSo/3nlK0uyD_p1CFvvGkbiQcGORv5w\"","eventId":null,"kind":"youtube#videoListResponse","nextPageToken":null,"prevPageToken":null,"visitorId":null}`

If I run the same request via the [YouTube API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list), I receive a response complete with snippet data and a full description.

[image: YouTube API Explorer Response]

So I ask, is the problem the [google/google-api-php-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) I am using, the YouTube API itself, or perhaps something else?

**Edit: I've found and thought about using [madcoda/php-youtube-api](https://github.com/madcoda/php-youtube-api) instead, and will do-so if all else fails.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've discovered that [google/google-api-php-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) was the problem here.

I've had success using [madcoda/php-youtube-api](https://github.com/madcoda/php-youtube-api) instead.